# Sending Batch Friends Request

Tags: facebook-graph-api, request

We are a Automobile Company Trying to Make an Closed Community of our Customers on Facebook.
There are about 900000 customers on out database. 
We have built an Application to Search for each customer via their email address or Mobile Number and Send them a Friend Request.
But Every-time we run the App, Only few hundred requests go out after which we get blocked out of our Facebook profile for 24 hours or so.

What is the correct way to achieve this without getting blocked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use custom audiences to anonymously find your customers and target them via some good ads. that's the only allowed way.

have a look at custom audiences here:
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/ads-api/custom-audience-targeting/